# Superblocks : Return a value and display it from a function in js. file to smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

Im doing a simple calculation Dapp in Superblocks,  does anybody here know how to get a value back from a smart contract function , I have it like this: 
In my js. file the :

```
//js. file 

function multiply () { let val = parseInt($("#cal").val());
instance.multiply.sendTransaction(val,{ from: accounts[0], gas : 300000}, 
function(error, result){
 if (error){
  alert(error);
    }
    else {
  $("#message").html(result.toString());
    }
```

}

```
//smart contract function
function multiply (uint num) public returns (uint){
num = testNum;
testNum += 1 ;
return testNum;
}
```

in which I thought that It would return the result ( testNum += 1) , but it returns the txHash … How can I pass a value to the smart contract function from my js. function that returns it back and then it displays it ? Sorry for the noob question, I`m new to Superblocks and Dapp development any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Transactions don't have return values. One possibility is to emit an event from your function with the value you want to "return" and look for that event on the client.

Comment: aha, so what is the difference between values :  instance.multiply.sendTransaction(val,{ from: accounts[0], gas : 300000}  and instance.multiply.sendTransaction(val,{ from: accounts[0], gas : 30000, value : val}, Im passing first one to the function as an argument and the second is accessible in the function just by msg.value ?